# Ubuntu Server don't boot anymore

Tags: boot, server, updates

I have an ubuntu server, that runs since a few month, and today, it tells me that i could run a command to update ubuntu. I did

And since, my server refuse to boot anymore.
Here is the screen i have
[image]

I can't scroll upper.

Sometimes when i reboot i got the grub menu, and i can select Ubuntu or advanced options for ubuntu.

Here is what i got in the advanced options
[image: Image2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IY09.png)

It seems i got 2 versions on my harddrive (probably the pre update and post update).

Anyone got an idea ? I'm out of idea right now ...

Thank you

Edit: if i go in recovery mod of the oldest version, that i do anything, and then i enter on "resume" the system is starting normally, but when i reboot, the problem come back

Comment: If you boot into the older -38 kernel, does your system work properly?

Answer (score 0):

did you start ubuntu kernel 5.0.0-38 generic  normally?

you have 2 kernel and i think the newest one is buggy so first
test the oldest one normal mode in advanced option, if its okay
you can uninstall new buggy kernel by

```
sudo dpkg --purge package name
```

and remove its directories give after deletion of linux kernel images
for findinf kernel depndencies packages,

```
dpkg -l | grep linux
```

then look for these

```
linux-headers-(kernel version)
linux-headers-(kernel version)-generic
linux-image-(kernel version)-generic   
linux-modules-(kernel version)-generic  
linux-modules-extra-(kernel version)-generic
```

remove them one by one
*Note :  if you want delete new kernel you should boot system in old kernel*

after complete uninstallation, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

it should work if old kernel working probably